# Strange prices from Amadeus

Tags: amadeus

I am checking the Amadeus about flight tickets and a little confused about the prices that I get. I expected to see prices from Amadeus closer to airline website prices or a little cheaper. But, I see that prices are incredibly high. For example, I made the following request:

```
https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=SGN&destinationLocationCode=DAD&departureDate=2020-05-29&adults=1&nonStop=true&currencyCode=VND

Flight at    Amadeus Price In USD   Airline price in USD
  11:45             ~70.41              ~38.72
  13:50             ~70.41              ~34.43
  18:00             ~70.41              ~42.93
```

Prices are higher significantly. Moreover, prices from Amadeus are the same for a lot of flights for the same air company.

Do I do something wrong or I skipped something?

PS: Response for first flight:

```
{
  "type": "flight-offer",
  "id": "1",
  "source": "GDS",
  "instantTicketingRequired": false,
  "nonHomogeneous": false,
  "oneWay": false,
  "lastTicketingDate": "2020-05-29",
  "numberOfBookableSeats": 4,
  "itineraries": [{
    "duration": "PT1H20M",
    "segments": [{
      "departure": {
        "iataCode": "SGN",
        "terminal": "1",
        "at": "2020-05-29T11:15:00"
      },
      "arrival": {
        "iataCode": "DAD",
        "terminal": "1",
        "at": "2020-05-29T12:35:00"
      },
      "carrierCode": "VJ",
      "number": "628",
      "aircraft": {
        "code": "321"
      },
      "operating": {
        "carrierCode": "VJ"
      },
      "duration": "PT1H20M",
      "id": "9",
      "numberOfStops": 0,
      "blacklistedInEU": false
    }]
  }],
  "price": {
    "currency": "VND",
    "total": "1640000.00",
    "base": "1381000.00",
    "fees": [{
        "amount": "0.00",
        "type": "SUPPLIER"
      },
      {
        "amount": "0.00",
        "type": "TICKETING"
      }
    ],
    "grandTotal": "1640000.00"
  },
  "pricingOptions": {
    "fareType": [
      "PUBLISHED"
    ],
    "includedCheckedBagsOnly": true
  },
  "validatingAirlineCodes": [],
  "travelerPricings": [{
    "travelerId": "1",
    "fareOption": "STANDARD",
    "travelerType": "ADULT",
    "price": {
      "currency": "VND",
      "total": "1640000.00",
      "base": "1381000.00"
    },
    "fareDetailsBySegment": [{
      "segmentId": "9",
      "cabin": "ECONOMY",
      "fareBasis": "JSP",
      "class": "J",
      "includedCheckedBags": {
        "weight": 20,
        "weightUnit": "KG"
      }
    }]
  }]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that right now the only source for prices in the API is GDS. Many LCCs don't / only load their more expensive fares into GDS, as it costs them money.

Lately, many "normal" airlines have also added fees when booking from a GDS compared to directly on their website / or other direct distribution methods.

I assume VietJet is one of those carriers, as it is a low-cost airline.

Regarding your second question: That is because of the fare system in the airline industry. Airlines load so called "fares", which specifies the price of a ticket for a given route within a date window.

An example: VietJet offers SGN-DAD for a base fare of 55EUR ( without taxes& fees ). You can choose any flight by VJ on any date within the window of the fare, and the price will be the same, as long as there is availability in the booking class J , which the fare is for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am completely new in this area, so, expected a little different from Amadeus. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If you are going for cheap prices, meta-search engines like Skyscanner will be better suited to you. Those will check a lot of offers on the internet from OTAs ( online travel agencies ). These are the offers, that are often times cheaper than booking directly with the airline.
Please be aware though, that booking through OTAs might be an issue, when there are irregularities, as their service standard isn't very high in many cases.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to understand how OTAs work. And why some of them have good prices. I am curious because my girlfriend started to sell flight tickets. She is Vietnamese, and here still popular to sell tickets and tours on Facebook. She found one agency here and they have very good prices, lower than on Skyscanner and on the airline website itself ( for Vietnamese airlines). The problem is she sells ticket "manually", she is looking for clients on Facebook and sell flights, tours. This agency doesn't have an API.

Comment: They just give access to the agent area. And I wanted to automate this for her and I though Amadeus has "source" prices and agencies just add their percent to this price. But it looks like I am completely wrong :) And everything is much complex.

Comment: Unfortunately, your plan might not work out that easily. OTAs have their own connection to GDS systems or they might have a contract with a consolidator. ( A consolidator is a company that buys airplane tickets in bulk from the airline and resells them to travel agencies, therefore they tend to be cheaper than normal tickets. These tickets are not commonly available, compared to "published" fares, which are accessible by every person).

Comment: Even if your girlfriend is an IATA agent / certified travel agent, it is difficult to automate the process. If you can get a contract with a consolidator, you can create bookings yourself ( by the Amadeus API) and have the tickets issued by the consolidator ( You need to be IATA certified to be able to issue tickets). But, for LCCs, you still have to go on their website manually and book the tickets there, because they don't offer any other way of sales, as far as I'm aware. Maybe a consolidator can give you cheap flights for LCCs if you manage to sell a lot of them, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: This is more a commercial/business discussion rather than a technical one (I am not sure StackOverflow is the best platform for this). Amadeus does offer specific APIs for IATA certified agents allowing them to manage the end-to-end flow and issue their reservations (but not in Self-Service). Amadeus offers access to LCC content as well (not in Self-Service for the moment). If you are interested, please contact us at developers@amadeus.com, we will then put you in contact with the right entity.

Comment: To add some (very high level) information: Skyscanner/Kayak are meta searches, they aggregate offers coming from different OTAs and directly from the airlines to find the best offers possible. OTAs are using GDS to get access to airlines' fares. There are different types of fares, the most common ones are public fares (the ones you get using the Self-Service APIs of Amadeus), those are fares that airlines offer through the GDS to all OTAs. The second one is negotiated fares: when an OTA is big enough they can negotiate with airlines better fares as they sell many seats for them.

Comment: You can find more information about how the travel industry works by checking the YouTube channel of Altexsoft (that I personally find very good).